# Different result for (apparantly) equal input data?

Tags: postgresql

To compute the average angle in a table (angles in degrees `[0, 360]`) I use the following statement:

```
SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN (a < 0.0) 
    THEN a + 360.0 
    ELSE a END) as angle
FROM (
    SELECT 
        degrees(atan2(avg(sin(radians(x))), avg(cos(radians(x))))) as a
    FROM
        angle_t
    ) as t
UNION
SELECT
    x
FROM
    angle_t
```

when it came to testing I tried my table containing yahoo weather data:

```
WITH angle_t(x) AS (
    SELECT 
        cast(wind_direction as double precision)
    FROM
        weather_yahoo
    WHERE 
        time >= current_date - interval '1 days' - interval '1 hours'
    AND 
        time <= current_date - interval '1 days')
```

The output was:

```
246.670436944698
250.0
240.0
```

I wondered why the average angle wasn't 245 but 246.67... so I ran another test with apparantly equal input data:

```
WITH angle_t(x) AS (VALUES 
    (240 :: double precision),
    (250))
```

The output showed the (un-)expected result:

```
245.0
250.0
240.0
```

Can anyone explain this to me? (this is PostgreSQL 8.4)

Comment: Without the data and table definitons it's kinda hard. SQLFiddle it?

Comment: From your question your running same input with two different solutions.  Your title is misleading.

Comment: @JustBob It turned out that it wasn't the same input, but it looked like same input. That's why I put _(apparantly)_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UNION` operator eliminates duplicate entries.

From [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-union.html) [emphasis mine]:

> UNION effectively appends the result of query2 to the result of query1 (although there is no guarantee that this is the order in which the rows are actually returned). **Furthermore, it eliminates duplicate rows from its result**, in the same way as DISTINCT, unless UNION ALL is used.

Therefore, if `UNION ALL` is used, the explanation for the unexpected outcome is obvious:

```
246.670436944698
250.0
240.0
250.0
```